# UIWebView resize

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiwebview

My webView is not resizing properly after it finished loading. I have tried this code.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webview {
    CGRect frame = webView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 1;
    frame.size.width = screenWidth;
    webView.frame = frame;
    CGSize fittingSize = [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    frame.size = fittingSize;
    webView.frame = frame;
    [bodyScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(screenWidth, webView.frame.origin.y + webView.frame.size.height+keyboardRectY+60)];
```

It is incresing the width beyond the screenWidth and hence my content horizontally expands beyond the view size which I don't want.

changing

```
CGSize fittingSize = [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(screenWidht, 1)];
```

also leads to the same situation.

How can I get rid of this? The webview width should always remain as screenwidth and only it's height should adjust based on the content size so that the webView just about fits the whole content.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
WebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

Comment: @amateurcoder Can you tell us why? If you're going to a web page designed for a wider screen (and I'm assuming you can just change that other page), then `scalesPageToFit` strikes me as a logical solution. Seems like that's precisely what that is designed for. What would you propose?